# I don't know what the green player is in warthunder

Tags: war-thunder

what is the green player? I am new really enjoying the game but it can be confusing.

Answer (score 7):

As @Jcraft153 was saying in the comments above.  The green players are in your Squad that you are (as of the Patch 1 year'ish ago) automatically assigned to at the beginning of each match.  This is all according to [Good Ol' Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Warthunder/comments/2ivp9q/players_with_green_names_since_the_patch/).  It can be toggled on and off in the settings.  BUT it is a good feature to keep on because you receive a "Teamwork" bonus if in close proximity of your Squad mates during a firefight.  I hope this helped!  Happy Hunting!

Answer (score 1):

They are your squadmates. You are suppose to work together with them. And when you do, you share some of the reward points. There is also a reward for the best team in the match.

Comment: you can also squad up with your friend(s) before spawning if you wish